# deploy lumen app with htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I want to deploy my lumen app on an webserver. I get following error

> "The server encountered an internal error due to .htaccess misconfiguration. Please check your .htaccess file within this or upper directories for syntax errors."

I checked my permissions and they are all set to `777`.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ mobile-app/index.php [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My Project structure is in root Directory there are the Contents of public-Folder and lumen contains all "lumen-Basic-Folders" like app, bootstrap, vendor, and so on...the root Directory contains also .htaccess file

Comment: Is the app working with this `.htaccess` file in a local development enviroment?